# Consuming WS over SSL using JAXWS

Tags: java, https, jax-ws

I'm trying to consume a webservice using JAX-WS client and https.

The problem now is that i successfully created an instance of the service and get the port of the service but when trying to consume a service using that port it gives connection timeout.

```
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.manuallyAuthorizeWithValidation(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure service is running using SOAP, 
if it's then try increasing the time 
if still not working, try to change the port

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the web service is running. You can use a tool such as SoapUI (free) to test SOAP web services.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  SkyPayService skyPayService = new SkyPayService();
  
  SkyPayServiceSoap skyPayServiceSoap = skyPayService.getSkyPayServiceSoap();
  
  Result manuallyAuthorizeResponse = skyPayServiceSoap.manuallyAuthorizeWithValidation("test","test");

  System.out.println(manuallyAuthorizeResponse.isSuccess());
  System.out.println(manuallyAuthorizeResponse.getMessage());
 }

Comment: Try increasing the timeout. How to do it depends on which Implementation you are using. I think the default timeout is 300.